# Storing of temporary submitted data in the back-end

Tags: mysql, rest, api, backend, document

I am developing a REST API for a university to be used by a website and a mobile app. We want a registration functionality where students choose the courses they want to enroll in and submit the result. The results are reviewed by an admin, and he confirms the registration. From the back-end point of view, the submissions are stored somewhere in a certain form on the server so that the admin can review them later. The question is what is the best way to do this? Should they be stored as documents in the storage? In a database? In what form?
Note that there are other functionalities in the app that are already implemented and I'm using MYSQL as a database.

Comment: MySQL is fine for such purposes. Make sure you sufficiently normalize your data.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic, as it's very broad (there are dozens of database solutions you could choose). It can also be seen as a tool/product recommendation question (already, you have people throwing out product names as solutions). A great discussion to have, but really no "right" answer.

Comment: Also: Your question mentions "temporary storage" which doesn't really align with a database or other storage mechanism.

Comment: I don’t think you read both question and my answer clearly before your comment

Comment: @wl.GIG I did, indeed, read both the question and the answer. My comments under the question aren't directed at you at all, but my assertion stands: the question is off-topic.

Comment: All I wanted to know is  the best way to store such data, not asking for a product to use.(MYSQL is a an example of an RDBMS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql is fine to do this. Basically, it is a many-to-many problem. The common way to deal with course enrollment service:

A **student** table with primary key, like student_id

```
student_id, student_name,.......
```

A **course** table with primary key, like course_id

```
course_id, course_name, course_context,.....
```

And key things here, a **mapping table** for course and student with status

```
student_id, 
course_id, //these two colunms are used for mapping
status, // as you menthond, it maybe a temporary submit. And it could be permitted or ..
```

It is the basic construct, and you can add your specific requirement  in these tables.

Comment: And, there are other problems like course and department,etc. If you need, I could help. BTW, my college course system s**ks.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Are you serious? It is not what my college course system did. I have graduated 12years.

Comment: "BTW, my college course system s**ks" <-- that's what I'm referring to.

Comment: What I want is to make him build better system for his student instead of ours

Answer (score 0):

You can keep going with MySql. Everything you described fits perfectly MySql.